# How to prove statement about $\mathcal{O}, \Theta$ and $\hbox{o}$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, asymptotics

For a given function g,

Prove that $\hbox{o}(g) \neq O(g) - Θ(g)$.

Thanks for the help in advance

Comment: I tried for different sets of functions like polynomials, exponential, sin, log, etc. Nothing works. I am unable to get functions f and g to satisfy the conditions. May be if I get I might prove they are not equal. I am new to this blog. Sorry for my unclear post. Thanks for the edit.

Comment: What does $f$ have to do with the rest of the question?

Comment: We need the get the LHS in terms of f and RHS in terms of f then prove they are not equal. I guess thats how we can prove :)

Comment: The way you have the question worded you are done. $f$ is the function that proves what you want to prove.

Comment: Yes, we need to prove with f. Guesses for f and g didnt work with me. So mathematical approach is the best one. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My comment apparently wasn't clear enough. The problem statement starts with let $f \in \mathcal{O}(g),~f \not\in \Theta(g)$ and $f \not\in \hbox{o}(g)$ so need to find $f$ or $g$ for this statement. We then quickly show that since $f \in \mathcal{O}(g),~f \not\in \Theta(g)$, we must have $f \in \mathcal{O}(g) - \Theta(g) = \{h\ |\ h \in \mathcal{O}(g) \mathrm{\ and\ } h \not\in \Theta(g)\}$. But we already know that $f \not\in \hbox{o}(g)$. Thus we have an element from the RHS which is not an element of the LHS so the two sides can not be equal as sets.

---

For two sets $A$ and $B$ to be equal, we must have that $A \subseteq B$ and $B \subseteq A$ where $\subseteq$ stands for subset. Formally, $A \subseteq B$ means that for any $x \in A$ we must have $x \in B$. So set equality basically says that pick anything from one set and we must be able to find it in the other set.

But in the problem above, we found a function $f$ that was part of one set but not part of the other set. Thus the two sets can not be equal.

Comment: How did you get f∈O(g)−Θ(g)={h | h∈O(g) and h∉Θ(g)} ?

Thanks :)

Comment: Just the definition of set subtraction. $A-B$ as sets means the set of all things that are in $A$ and not in $B$.

Comment: How can we relate that to LHS? I am new to this notations. Sorry for the trouble.

Comment: Edited answer to describe a little more detail about the sets.

Comment: Sorry dude, I made a mistake. f∈O(g), f∉Θ(g) and f∉o(g) is not given. We just need to prove that o(g)≠O(g)−Θ(g). Sorry for the trouble.

Comment: Not a problem. With what is given in the answer above you know what you need to find. You need $f\in\mathcal{O}(g)$ but $f\not\in\Theta(g), f\not\in\hbox{o}(g)$.

Comment: Yes,But I am unable to assume any f and g to suit that. Any theoretical way to solve?

Comment: I am really sorry for the inconvenience. But I dont know how to proceed. Help please:)

Comment: I'm thinking about it. I suspect you will need to create a "funny" function for $f$.

Comment: Will this work f = 0 for even and 1 for odd and g = n ?

Comment: Looks good. You should obviously double-check the formal definitions.